# javascript show hide division download content

Tags: javascript, show-hide

I have a javscript show / hide script which takes division Id as a parameter. I am building a website where (on the same page), the same file is present multiple times. The show / hide code is called as follows:

```
<p class="MsoNormal"><a href="javascript:switchid('19940530_id');">ClickMe</a> to see me (p element). Note arrow displayed</p>
<div style="display: none;  padding-left: 10px" id="19940530_id">
  <p class="MsoNormal">Now you see me (p element).</p>
</div>
```

Problem is that to do this and have the correct div show / hide, the id's must be unique, requiring multiple identical files, differing only by id to be downloaded. This makes for slow page loading.

I seek a way to dynamically assign or determine a unique id (at load time?) to pass to this script.

The show / hide code is here: https://www.rossco.org/include/scripts/manage_showhide.js

And, a demo (with a "wish" change list) is here: https://www.rossco.org/showhide.html

Suggestions?

Thanks;
Bill

Comment: the Q is independent of code. How to dynamically assign the div id parameter in the html?

Comment: Simply with `setAttribute('id', 'dynamic-id')`!

Comment: Thanks Chaymin; Did a quick search on setAttribute('id', 'dynamic-id') and (noob) not sure how to incorporate in above html. I can certainly change the id within the div with a script block containing your code, but, how do I pass the new id to the script? Care to post an example? Thanks, Bill

Answer (score 0):

You should use `setAttribute('id', ...)` with the dynmaic id, and then you ned a way to pass the id of the element should be toggled - I will do it with [data- attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes):

```js
var container = document.querySelector('#container');
var idsNum = 0;

document.querySelector('#addElement').addEventListener('click', function() {
  var parent = document.createElement('div');
  
  var uniqueId = 'id' + (idsNum++);
  
  var paragraph = document.createElement('p');
  paragraph.textContent = 'Some text.'; // Use innerText for old browsers
  paragraph.setAttribute('id', uniqueId);
  
  var toggleBtn = document.createElement('button');
  toggleBtn.textContent = 'Toggle Paragraph Visiblity'; // Use innerText for old browsers
  toggleBtn.setAttribute('data-id', uniqueId);
  toggleBtn.addEventListener('click', handleClick, false);
  
  parent.appendChild(paragraph);
  parent.appendChild(toggleBtn);
  
  container.appendChild(parent);
}, false);

function handleClick(e) {
  e = e || window.event;
  
  var toggledElement = document.getElementById(e.target.getAttribute('data-id'));
  toggledElement.style.display = 'none' === toggledElement.style.display ? '' : 'none';
}
```

```html
<button id="addElement">Add Element</button>

<div id="container"></div>
```

But, if any paragraph & button have a unique parent, you don't need to generate id dynmically, and instead, you should simply toggle the `p` tag inside the parent of the clicked button (I added a class to all `p` tags beacuse maybe there are another paragraphs inside the parent):

```js
var container = document.querySelector('#container');

document.querySelector('#addElement').addEventListener('click', function() {
  var parent = document.createElement('div');
  
  var paragraph = document.createElement('p');
  paragraph.textContent = 'Some text.'; // Use innerText for old browsers
  paragraph.className = 'paragraph';
  
  var toggleBtn = document.createElement('button');
  toggleBtn.textContent = 'Toggle Paragraph Visiblity'; // Use innerText for old browsers
  toggleBtn.addEventListener('click', handleClick, false);
  
  parent.appendChild(paragraph);
  parent.appendChild(toggleBtn);
  
  container.appendChild(parent);
}, false);

function handleClick(e) {
  e = e || window.event;
  
  var toggledElement = e.target.parentNode.querySelector('.paragraph');
  toggledElement.style.display = 'none' === toggledElement.style.display ? '' : 'none';
}
```

```html
<button id="addElement">Add Element</button>

<div id="container"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that attempting to make the Id's unique was overly complex and far better to use a more modern jquery, CSS, OO approach, since my site already uses it. Plus, having buttons for show / hide makes a very ugly UI when dealing with many show / hide divs. I wanted to be able to click on the text and have an unobtrusive indication of whether a section is shown or hidden.

demo here: https://www.rossco.org/showhide-new.html

code:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Show / Hide Demo</title>
<script src="https://www.rossco.org/browse.php?Frameworks/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://www.rossco.org/include/css/ms_office.css">
<style>
.toggle {
 display: block;
}
.toggle p {
 color: blue;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  // Initialize all toggle div arrows hidden
  var divs = document.getElementsByClassName("toggle");
  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
    var oldHTML = divs[i].firstElementChild.innerHTML;
    divs[i].firstElementChild.innerHTML = "<img src=\"/images/plus.gif\" alt=\"hide section\" />" + oldHTML;
  }
  // Start all showhide divs with display: none (hidden)
  divs = document.getElementsByClassName("showhide");
  for (i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
    divs[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  $(".toggle").on("click", function(e)
  {
    var oldHTML = e.target.innerHTML;
    var newHTML = "";
    // Image tags already created by page load, need to toggle
    if ( e.currentTarget.nextElementSibling.style.display == "none" )
    {
       e.currentTarget.nextElementSibling.style.display = "";
       newHTML = oldHTML.replace("plus.gif", "minus.gif");
    } else {
       e.currentTarget.nextElementSibling.style.display = "none";
       newHTML = oldHTML.replace("minus.gif", "plus.gif");
    }
    e.target.innerHTML = newHTML;
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="toggle">
    <p class="MsoNormal">Click to see me.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="showhide">
      <p class="MsoNormal">Now you see me (p element).</p>
      <p class="MsoNormal">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
  </div>

  <div class="toggle">
      <p class="MsoNormal">Click to see me (li element).</p>
  </div>
  <div class="showhide">
      <li class="MsoNormal">Now you see me (li element).</li>
      <li class="MsoNormal">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

To use this code:

1 - change jquery script src to standard jquery url

2 - replace p and li classes from MsoNormal to your own.

3 - (optional) split css and javascript out and incorporate with your site css and javascript

Html is simple:

```
<div class="toggle">
  <p class="whatever">Text to click to see.</p>
</div>
<div class="showhide">
  <p class="whatever">Text to show / hide.</p>
  ... any other valid html content
</div>
```

Since javascript is just an occasional competency, appreciate comments / flames / suggestions regarding browser or any other issues, before I commit to changing hundreds of files.

Regards;
Bill